# Play Protect Doesn't recognize this app's developer

Tags: unity, android

I am a game developer. This message is displayed when installing my game. what is this? and how to solve this problem?[image]

Comment: Thank you for removing the [cross-post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347252/play-protect-doesnt-recognize-this-apps-developer-message). I've re-opened your question here.

Comment: Do you mean that you see this message when you install the app through its .apk directly rather than through the Play Store?

Comment: Stackoverflow same problem, solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080755/installation-app-blocked-by-play-protect